# How to make Firefox honour my configuration to disable font hinting for a single font?

Tags: x11, firefox, fonts, fontconfig

I am using **Debian GNU/Linux version 8** with **LXDE**. Regarding fonts, I have my system configured to use anti‐aliasing, subpixel rendering, and full hinting. However, I want to disable hinting for Liberation Serif, but it does not work in Firefox. Firefox still uses full hinting for Liberation Serif. However, Liberation Serif is correctly shown as non‐hinted in other programs (I checked in Gucharmap, Leafpad and LibreOffice Writer).

How can I disable hinting for all serif fonts or just Liberation Serif in Firefox?

I have hinting set to full with the customizer that comes with LXDE and the following code in `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` and `~/.fonts.conf` (the later is a symbolic links to the former):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
      <const>lcddefault</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Liberation Serif</string></test>
    <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
      <const>hintnone</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to about:config
Find the preference gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode
Change its value (probably -1) to 1

1 turns anti-aliasing off.
You might also want to try 2 and 3.

4 and 5 are not your friends, they involve anti-aliasing.

That turns off both anti-aliasing, and font-hinting.

OR You Can Try Belows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
      <const>lcddefault</const>
</edit>
  </match>
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Liberation Serif</string></test>
   <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
   <bool>false</bool>
   </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: No such setting at all in Firefox 64.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could explore options from Firefox advanced config.

Type `about:config` on address text bar and hit Enter. You will be warned that changes from there are dangerous for Firefox stability. There's nothing wrong with that unless you change something critical. Accept the risk, and try some changes (once at a time). Search "font_rendering" or "font" options. Maybe you could do something from there.

I also have to say I've never had this problem or wanted to work this way.